# detecting potential race condition on compile time in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, attributes, static-analysis

With Visual C++, [`_Guarded_by_`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/annotating-locking-behavior) and its static analysis feature detects potential race conditions in compile time.

Is there any equivalent thing in C#, for example, adding a attribute on a variable which detects race condition by human mistake?

Comment: If you have the requirements, you can pretty easily make your own - Roslyn makes it very easy to do code analysis. But I doubt it will be added to the language itself, since it only makes sense for a very limited way of writing multi-threaded code that is kind of frowned upon in modern C#, and you can easily add it yourself if you really want.

Comment: "Roslyn makes it very easy to do code analysis. " - Can I add my custom rule for static analysis in C#? Amazing.

Comment: Yup. And you can have it be a warning or compile-time error, whatever you want. You can also add your own automated code fixes and everything. There's even loads of helper methods specifically to help with doing stuff like flow control analysis.

Comment: Thank you for letting know it. Would you introduce any start point for learning how to do it, e.g. URL? @Luaan

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty much out of luck. Check the [open github issue here](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/892)

> **Keyword #1: guardedby (ISyncobject 1, [ISyncobject 2], …) [auto]**
>
> Sync object = A special thread synchronization class – Similar variations like, monitor, semaphore, readerwriterlock, etc.
>   Use for a class, Method, Property, or field.
>   Summary: Adding to a class, method, property or field tells the compiler to check to see if the lock for the synchronization object was acquired for this thread. If the sync object is not locked when a protected method, property, field is encountered an UnguardedAreaException() will be thrown.

It's been requested for quite some time and it is still an open issue, despite people requesting it.